# how to handle android low battery popup interrupt?

Tags: android, android-activity, cocos2d-x

I have game in cocos2d-x 3.4
I have problem with low battery pop-up & title bar interruption.
On this two interrupt onPause()/onResume() is not getting called.

So do i have to handle this with any other activity method or what?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the answer if anyone needs it in future,

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if(hasFocus) {
        // Resume logic
        Cocos2dxHelper.onResume();
        this.mGLSurfaceView.onResume();
    }
    else {
        // Pause logic
        Cocos2dxHelper.onPause();
        this.mGLSurfaceView.onPause();
    }
}
```

It will work for low battery pop-up notification as well as for Title bar dragging interruption.

Answer (score -1):

low battery pop up belong to system notification we cannot handle it. May be you can check the battery level prior starting game and notify user about it

thanks.

Comment: than How other games handling it? Check out major games even on dragging title bar game is getting paused. I have solution for iOS but not getting for android.